# fcgi extension apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu, fastcgi

I've been playing around with fastcgi lately and I'm having trouble accessing *.fcgi files while omitting the extension.  In ubuntu + apache2 + libapache2-mod-php5 php files can be accessed without putting the extension in the url.  I've looked in my sites-available folder and I have +Multiviews set.  I've looked into php5.conf and configured my fastcgi.conf similarly but I didn't get the same result.  Does anybody have experience accessing fastcgi without extension or is there anyone savy in apache who knows how that's done.